# Transform dataframes columns names in a specific way

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
ID   value  is_valid
A    134     TRUE
B    345     FALSE
C    131     TRUE
```

I want to make it one rows with 9 columns, so there will be same columns for each of ID. So, desired result must look like this:

```
A_ID   A_value  A_is_valid  B_ID   B_value  B_is_valid  C_ID   C_value  C_is_valid
A        134     TRUE        B       345     FALSE       C       131     TRUE
```

How could i do that? I have no idea

Comment: Seems to work directly : `tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = ID, values_from = -ID)`

Answer (score 0):

We can create a sequence column and use `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(rn = LETTERS[row_number()]) %>% 
     pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = -rn)
# A tibble: 1 x 9
#  ID_A  ID_B  ID_C  value_A value_B value_C is_valid_A is_valid_B is_valid_C
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <int>   <int>   <int> <lgl>      <lgl>      <lgl>     
#1 A     B     C         134     345     131 TRUE       FALSE      TRUE
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), value = c(134L, 345L, 131L
), is_valid = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: thanks, and is it possible without writing down all columns like here "values_from = c(ID, value, is_valid)"? I would like to apply as a function to different data frames with different number of columns (but they all have column ID)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `reshape`

```
reshape(
  cbind(P = 1, Q = df$ID, df),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "P",
  timevar = "Q"
)[-1]
```

which gives

```
  ID.A value.A is_valid.A ID.B value.B is_valid.B ID.C value.C is_valid.C
1    A     134       TRUE    B     345      FALSE    C     131       TRUE
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), value = c(134L, 345L, 131L
), is_valid = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```